# Error: no appropriate default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, default

Not able to compile the following. whats wrong here?

```
class B;
class A
{
public:
    void DoSomething()
    {
        ...
        B* myb = new B();
        ...
    }
};

class B
{ 
public:
B() {}
};
```

Comment: what is the error and put the entire code pls.

Comment: Full definition of `B` needs to be visible before you can create an instance of it. A forward declaration alone is not sufficient.

Comment: C2512 is the error code. "'B':No appropriate default constructor is available " @Igor Tandetnik - you are right I guess. But how to resolve this?

Comment: I was trying 'State pattern where concrete state objects will set to another state inside their public methods. If the definition of B is not visible, how A state object can set the context state to B?

Comment: You resolve this by making the definition of `B` available before you attempt to create an instance of it, of course. I thought that much was obvious.

Comment: Like in the case of two state objects, what if both A and B compose the other in their body? at least one will complain about the other.

Comment: @Anand: At least one will have to keep only a pointer or reference to the other and make the type name known via a forward declaration.

Answer (score 1):

`new B()` requires the complete definition of the type. A forward declaration is not sufficient.

Which makes sense. For example, who says `B` even has a public default constructor? You cannot know that before `B`'s complete definition is known.

Answer (score 1):

You do the forward declaration in order to know that some `class B` exists, although it's not defined yet. In this case you don't even need to do that because there is no member in `class A` of type `B`.

Just declare the `doSomething` method, and define it later after `B` is defined

```
class A {
    ...
    void doSomething(); // declared
    ...
};

class B {
    ...
};

// define doSomething after defining class B or in the .cpp source file
void A::doSomething() {
    B *myb = new B();
    ...
}
```

Though usually you would use header/source files so it would be more practical to separate the declaration from the definition.

---

**EDIT**

If both A and B refer to each other then you need to write a forward declaration in one of them (or both).

```
// A.h
class B;
class A {
    ...
    B *_myB;
};

// A.cpp
#include "B.h"

void A::doSomething() {
    _myB = new B();
}
```

---

```
// B.h
class A;
class B {
    ...
    A *_myA;
};

// B.cpp
#include "A.h"

void B::doSomething() {
    _myA = new A();
}
```

A forward declaration allows you to have a pointer to that type, such as `B*`. But not a complete type `B`, because the size of `B` is not known but `B*` is the same size of any other pointer.

You could have made one of them store a complete type by including the other class in the header file, but not both.

Anyway it wouldn't make sense if you could include dependent complete types. Then an instance of `A` would instantiate a member `B` which would in turn instantiate its member `A`, and so on.

Comment: awesome. Thats what I must do. Thank you very much to show light towards a very simple and must to remember technique.

Answer (score 0):

When you forward declare a type, you are telling the compiler that such a type exists.But the Compiler has no idea about the size or members of that type.

You generally use a forward declaration to break circular dependencies.

```
class B;
class A
{
public:
    void DoSomething()
    {
        ...
        B* myb ;            ...
    }
};
```

This will work since you only have a pointer to that type.

This has been discussed in detail here:
[forward reference usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration)

Answer (score 0):

```
class B;
```

The declaration above (forward declaration) introduces the name **B** into the compiler. After the declaration and before the definition is seen, type **B** is an **incomplete type**.

The use of **incomplete type** is limited. For example, a pointer or a reference can be defined to such type. However, it is not possible;

- to create objects of that type (compiler doesn't know size of the class)
- to access a member of that type (compiler doesn't know what member the class has)

In the code in question;

```
B* myb = new B();
```

is after the declaration and before the definition is seen.